# How can I make church bells with a pull cord?

Tags: technic, design, castle

I would like to allow the viewer to pull on some strings or chains and let that ring my church bells (I know it won't make much sound, that's fine).  I'm thinking I'll need a [pulley](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4185&name=Technic,%20Wedge%20Belt%20Wheel%20(Pulley)&category=%5BTechnic%5D#T=C) and some [string](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=x77#T=S&O=%7B%22st%22:%224%22,%22ss%22:%22US%22,%22rpp%22:%22100%22,%22iconly%22:0%7D), right? Then, do I just thread the axle through the pulley and attach the axle to the bell somehow? Are there any other parts I might need? Is there a good tutorial you can recommend for LEGO pulleys?

Comment: There's no real need to stick with LEGO strings. Any other, similar thickness, string would work the same way and will be cheaper and easier to obtain. This allows you to go with longer strings too.

Comment: Is there something I do to attach the string to the pulley?

Comment: I don't quite imagine the model/setup you are looking to implement, so cannot really advise anything reasonable.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to implement a fairly simple bell mechanism such as this one:

[image: Bell with rope and pulley]

You can certainly do this using some string and the pulley element that you mentioned.

I'd recommend tying the string to one of the holes in the pulley. Something like this worked reasonably well for me:

[image: Pulley view]

[image: Back view]

[image: Front view]

Here it is in action:

[image: Bell animation]

You'll likely want to do something to limit the range of motion so that the bell can't flip all the way around when the string is pulled too far. You should obviously make everything a lot prettier, too.

Comment: and maybe add a secret latch or something just in case it messes up